# After I installed 14.04 desktop, launcher on left side is missing after Virtualbox 4.3.12 upgrade

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

Exactly same issue as the [MAIN POST](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) 
But the solutions given in that post didn't solve the issue.

I was working with VirtualBox 4.3.10 in Windows 8 with Ubuntu 14.04 as Guest. Once I upgraded to Virtualbox 4.3.12, then suddenly launcher and taskbar is missing. 
No Terminal working.

Please note, I have tried the options in the MAIN post. So this seems to be another kind of issue.

Comment: did you, after VBox upgrade also upgrade the guest additions?

Comment: @Takkat, yes mate.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work:

Log in like normal.
Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to log in to TTY1.

Run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
export DISPLAY=:0
ccsm
```

When you run ccsm it may hang and not return to the prompt. It doesn't matter. Just press Ctrl+Alt+F7 (or Ctrl+Alt+F8 sometimes) to get back to the graphical display where there should be a CompizConfig Settings Manager screen sitting there. Find the Unity plugin. Enable it. You will also have to enable all dependencies. Close ccsm.

Return to TTY1 by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1

Run the following:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
unity --reset-icons &disown
```

This may take a minute to run.
When it is done run:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: didn't work for me :(